# How to add a Crawl Content for specific fields in User Profile?

Tags: crawling

I have added 3 fields in the user profile (userGroup, UserAccounts, UserRegion). I would like add a Crawl Content on this fields. How? I tried adding a new content source with sps3://mysite.spsite.com but it errors out "the start address already exists in this or another content source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a managed property in the search administration that maps onto the custom properties. You can find the managed properties admin link in the left hand menu of the search admin page.